# how can i get 80 bit floats to work in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

In numpy (or python in general), I would like to take advantage of the fact that Intel x86 FPUs natively support 80 bit long double data types. How can i do that. On my machine (intel core i7, macOS Catalina, python 3.8.1, numpy 1.19.1) the following attempt seems to fail, because additional digits seem not to be preserved:

```
>>> scalar = np.array([1.4756563577476488347],dtype=np.float64)
... with np.printoptions(precision=100,suppress=False):
...     print(scalar)
[1.475656357747649]


>>> scalar = np.array([1.4756563577476488347],dtype=np.float128)
... with np.printoptions(precision=100,suppress=False):
...     print(scalar)
[1.4756563577476489169]

>>> scalar = np.array([1.4756563577476488347],dtype=np.longfloat)
... with np.printoptions(precision=100,suppress=False):
...     print(scalar)
[1.4756563577476489169]
```

It seems strange, because the data types seem to be what i think they are (64 bit vs. 80 bit):

```
print(np.finfo(np.float64))

Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

print(np.finfo(np.float128))

Machine parameters for float128
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  18   resolution = 1.0000000000000000715e-18
machep =    -63   eps =        1.084202172485504434e-19
negep =     -64   epsneg =     5.42101086242752217e-20
minexp = -16382   tiny =       3.3621031431120935063e-4932
maxexp =  16384   max =        1.189731495357231765e+4932
nexp =       15   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does it have anything to do with the ability to parse the input number?

Comment: `np.longdouble?` Note that it is platform dependent. I get 128 bits on my xeon

Comment: Here is the documentation confirming that: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision

Comment: The literal becomes a Python float first, with value 1.4756563577476489168560647158301435410976409912109375.

Comment: I also tried np.longdouble. It seems to be exactly the same as np.float128 and np.longfloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that *Python* uses only 64 bit floating point, and you are passing a Python object to `np.array`.

Try this:

```
In [26]: scalar = np.array(['1.4756563577476488347'], dtype=np.float128)                                    

In [27]: with np.printoptions(precision=100, suppress=False): 
    ...:     print(scalar) 
    ...:                                                                                                   
[1.4756563577476488347]
```

By using a string for the literal, the code to create the `float128` object is now in NumPy, which will preserve the precision of the value.

Comment: Makes sense. I wasn't aware of the fact that the np.array() function can parse string literals.